# Installing ClickOnce from several URLs

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that needs to be setup from several [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). For example that I need it to be installed from the following URLs:

```
http://mycompany.com//url1
http://mycompany.com//url2
```

I publish it based on installing from `url1` (publish wizard -> page two -> from web specify the URL: url1), but when I try to copy it to `url2`, it still looks at `url1`.

To do this, I set the installation folder URL to

```
http://mycompany.com//url1
```

and checked *Exclude deployment provider URL* and published the application to a directory on my pc and then I copied it to the server.

How can I force it to use `url2` when the installation is started from a index.html on `url2`?

### Edit1

I did several tests to see why what is happening.

The publish wizard creates a HTML file called `index.htm`.

In this HTML file, there is a button that has a reference to setup.exe. When this application runs, it looks for .application from `url1`. I checked and there is no reference to `url1` in the HTML file, but setup.exe looks at .application from `url1`.

If I delete all files from `url1`, but all of them exist on `url2`, the application setup fails by an error that it can not find http:\mycompany.com\url1\myapplication.application.

If I create a new version of the application and upload it to `url1`, then go `url2` and try to install it, the newer application is installed, but no update happens.

My settings are:

```
Options:
  Deployment
      Automatically generate deployment... Set
      Open deployment web                  Set
      Use .dep file ex                     Not set
      For CD installation, aut             Set
      Verify files uploaded to a web sever Not set
 Manifests
      Block application from               Not set
      Allow URL parameters to pass         Not set
      Use application manifest for trust   Not set
      Exclude deployment provider URL      Set
      Create desktop shortcut              Set
Publish location
        publish/
Installation folder URL
        http://MyCompany.com/url1
This application is available offline      Set

Publish wizard
     How the user install the application:
      From a web site URL =url1
      Yes this application is available online and off line set.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is really weird - please make sure you indeed deleted everything from both URLs. After you generate ClickOnce deployment files with "Exclude Deployment Provider URL" option, there is no mention of the installation URL in the <<your application name>>.application file - so from my point of view, there are two possible scenarios:

1. You copied the wrong (old) deployment files into the URL2 folder (or did not override them).
2. You are doing a manual update from your application with URL1 hardcoded somewhere.

In my case exactly same scenario works as it should work - multiple URLs - multiple installations.

Comment: do string search for "http://mycompany.com/url1" in ALL generated ClickOnce files - any match?.